# Symfony2 - Programmatically set remember me cookie

Tags: symfony, cookies

I have implemented a custom authenticator through the new simple_form functionnality

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        simple_form:
            authenticator: custom_authenticator
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 jours
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
            name: my_remember_cookie
```

The authenticateToken() method from my Authenticator looks like:

```
try {
    $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
    throw new AuthenticationException('Unknown user');
}
if ($user->isLocked() === true) {
    throw new AuthenticationException('User locked');
}
if (/* Logic checks */) { 
    return new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles()
    );
}
```

I was wondering if, from this point, there is a method to programmatically set the remember me cookie (in my case i want to set it according to the user's role) ?

**Edit: I solved it thanks to sebbo**, the whole point is to manually set the remember_me parameter in the $request object before passing it to the rememberMe service.

My final code:

```
/**
 * onAuthenticationSuccess
 * 
 * @param     Request $request
 * @param     TokenInterface $token
 * @return     Response
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    $url = $this->container->get("session")->get('_security.main.target_path') ? $this->container->get("session")->get('_security.main.target_path') : $this->container->get("router")->generate('home');
    $response = $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ?
            new JsonResponse(array(
                "success" => true,
                "url" => $url
            )) : new RedirectResponse($url);
    // Relevant part
    $rememberMeService = $this->container->get("EDE.security.service.remember_me");
    $request->attributes->set($rememberMeService->getRememberMeParameter(), 'true'/*set to other than 'yes'|'true'|'on'|'1' to force to don't set cookie*/);
    $rememberMeService->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);
    return $response;
}
```

The service alias:

```
<service id="EDE.security.service.remember_me" alias="security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.main"></service>
```

The manual request parameter assignment seems a little bit dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the remember me cookie programmatically we are using the following code in our application:

```
// setting the remember me token
$this->container->get('our_company.security.service.remember_me')->loginSuccess(
    $request,
    $response,
    $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()
);
```

Consider that the service definition for `our_company.security.service.remember_me` is only an alias for the Symfony2 remember me service. We had to create this alias to make the remember me service public.

This is the service definition:

```
<service id="our_company.security.service.remember_me" alias="security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.main"/>
```

Comment: Works great. YAML syntax for service definition:

`our_company.security.service.remember_me: { alias: security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.main }`