# Remember me does not work with JSON login

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

After setting up `form_login` and `json_login` as said in documentation everything worked fine in my application. Then I got a task to add **Remember me** functionality.  Having followed the docs, I've updated `security.yaml` and it worked but only for the form associated with `form_login`, even though the `json_login` key has inner key `remember_me` set to true (this is the default). You can see this key with `bin/console config:dump-reference security`, couldn't find it in docs. Before I managed to make it work for JSON login with some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998131/symfony2-programmatically-set-remember-me-cookie/24999346) I'd dived deep into Security Component and after investigating the whole process I can't see where the **Remember me** cookie could be set while JSON login. The `UsernamePasswordJsonAuthenticationListener` is not even extending `AbstractAuthenticationListener`. It only implements `ListenerInterface` and that's all! What's more, in SecurityBundle the class `JsonLoginFactory` overrides method `isRememberMeAware()` and returns `false`.

So my question is - am I missing something or there is no remember me functionality added when using `json_login` and the `remember_me` key for this one is useless?

Comment: I just noticed this myself today. I can't figure out the process of adding a remember_me to the json_login. Were you able to do it? If so, how? Is this a bug?

Comment: First, make private service `security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.main` public by aliasing it in your `services.yaml` so you can use it in DI. Name it however you want. Then, in your request `attributes` field (which is an instance of `ParameterBag`)  you have to manually set new attribute which will have the name configured under `security.firewalls.main.json_login.remember_me_parameter` and value `true`. Finally, call method `loginSuccess` on this new service and pass the required arguments. I did the whole job inside `success_handler` for my `json_login`.

Comment: P.S. I've noticed that in Symfony 4.2 this service is public and aliased by it's FQCN.

Comment: Any news about the implementation ?